# Using INNER JOIN twice to replace columns gets Ambiguous Name Error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of bicycle trips (`bixi_august`) and a table of bicycle docking stations (`bixi_stations`). `bixi_august` only has station codes, and the names are stored in `bixi_stations.name`.

I'm trying to write a query which shows the most common trips, but displays the the more readable station names, instead of the codes.

When I put in the following, I get `SQL error or missing database (ambiguous column name: bixi_stations.name)`:

```
SELECT bixi_stations.name as 'Start Station', bixi_stations.name as 'End 
Station', COUNT(*)
FROM bixi_august
INNER JOIN bixi_stations ON bixi_august.start_station_code=bixi_stations.code
INNER JOIN bixi_stations ON bixi_august.end_station_code=bixi_stations.code
GROUP BY bixi_august.start_station_code, bixi_august.end_station_code
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

I'm basically trying to get this, but without the station codes displayed in the table.

```
SELECT bixi_stations.name as 'Start Station name', start_station_code, bixi_stations.name as 'End Station', end_station_code, COUNT(*) as 'Total Trips'
FROM bixi_august
INNER JOIN bixi_stations ON bixi_august.start_station_code=bixi_stations.code
GROUP BY start_station_code, end_station_code
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

I'm fairly new to SQL, and Googling/searching hasn't helped me out here. I get the feeling that my issues is having `bixi_stations.name` twice in my select statement, without disambiguate how the inner joins should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need table aliases to distinguish the table references:

```
SELECT ss.name as Start_Station, se.name as End_Station, COUNT(*)
FROM bixi_august a INNER JOIN
     bixi_stations ss
     ON a.start_station_code = ss.code INNER JOIN
     bixi_stations se
     ON a.end_station_code = be.code
GROUP BY ss.name, se.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Note the changes I've made to the query:

- The tables now have convenient abbreviations (called *table aliases*).
- The aliases are used for all column referenced (*qualified column names*).
- The `GROUP BY` columns are the same as the `SELECT` columns.

Comment: Your solution worked, and I tried converting it myself to get a feel for it was well. Thanks! Syntax-wise, why indent after the first INNER JOIN?

Comment: @JimPrideaux . . . SQL queries have a collect of main clauses, the most common of which are `SELECT`, `FROM`, WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY`.  I left indent those.  `JOIN` is not a main clause, neither is `ON`.  `JOIN` is an operator, I put operators at the end of a row.  That leaves `ON` to be indented as a subsidiary clause to `JOIN`.  I do actually explain this in Chapter 1 of "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".